# How to change label position for ipad to fill the space

Tags: ios, ipad, uilabel, uistackview

I have two labels and represent them in two rows line one under another.

Now i want that if a user opens the app on ipad then two labels will show in single row (next to each other)

i followed this tutorial ([sample tutorial](https://www.natashatherobot.com/magical-view-rotation-with-stackview/))
it is for horizontal and vertical rotation and it is working on storyboard not on device.

kindly help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: put your project on the github (or other version control system) and shere it with us.. you could have made a mistake anywhere, but without your code it is very hard to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them in a `UIStackView` and set it's axis vertical , click `+` icon and select horizontal for W r, H r

Comment: @ParvBhasker If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark under the voting arrows.

Answer (score 2):

You can use StackView and add variation for iPad as follows:

[image]

[image]

Now you can have labels in single row in iPad
[image]

If you don't want to use StackView then you have to alter the autolayout using SizeClass.

Hope this will help you :)